# Actionbarsherlock orientation change indeterminate progressbar stops spinning

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a refresh menu item in the action bar and my main layout just consists of a button.
so clicking on the refresh menu item should turn it into a spinner and click on the button should stop it spinning.
My problem is that when i hit on the refresh button it starts spinning which is correct but now when i rotate it it stops spinning automatically.

this is my activity.

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockActivity implements OnClickListener{

View refreshView =  null;
com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem refreshItem = null;
Animation rotateClockwise = null;
Button btn = null;
boolean downloadComplete = false;
boolean selected = false;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    // Inflate our custom layout.

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    refreshView = (View) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress, null);
    refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh);
    if (selected){
        refreshItem.setActionView(refreshView);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(
        final com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_refresh:
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Apply the View to our MenuItem
                item.setActionView(refreshView);
            }
        });
        // Refresh the data
        //refresh();
        selected =true;
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    downloadComplete = !downloadComplete;
    selected = false;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            refreshItem.setActionView(null);
        }
    });
}
}
```

This is my res/layout/actionbar_indeterminate_progress.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ProgressBar android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="?android:attr/indeterminateProgressStyle" />
</FrameLayout>
```

my res/layout/activity_my.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MyActivity" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my res/menu/my_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Refresh"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
        android:title="Settings">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is an activity is destroyed and then created again on the orientation change. You need to do two things:

1. Save the value of the *selected* field before orientation changes.  Details on how to handle orientation change can be found in [Handling configuration changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ConfigurationChanges) section and more in [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).
2. When the activity is re-created after the orientation change, re-store *selected* field and use its value to start the animation if the value is true.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that situation but i guess thats the only way to go. thanxs